# Centos 7 boot and installation problem

Tags: centos

I have installed centos 7 as a webserver a while ago using software raid 0 LVM on installing centos for the first time. It was running smooth but recently I have got some  error while opening the system.

[image]

[image]

While I could not understand how to solve it So I have decided to install a fresh copy of centos in it again and created a bootable usb using Yumi multiboot USB software with the latest centos7 DVD 1511 iso

But when I was trying to install centos using usb on it was showing these error here are the image for it

```
https://i.stack.imgur.com/qWQAu.jpg 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/G9D56.jpg
```

Please help me how can I fix the old installation or make a fresh installation on it. I was using 3 hard drives 1 SATA SM: Samsung 256 GB for only the centos instllation and then 2 hard drives of 2, SATA SM: Toshiba DT01ACA100, 3- SATA PM: Toshiba DT01ACA200 for storage using LVM software raid 0

Comment: A RAID0 was probably a bad idea - do you know how your data was spread over them ?   
What backups do you have - could you rebuild this server from those backups ?
Have you run    xfs_repair /dev/sdc1   from a boot disk as per the suggestion in your photo?

Comment: How can I repair that?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have adequate backups that will let you rebuild the server from a fresh install?

If yes, replace the failing drive/s, reinstall on a RAID1 and then restore.

If you lack backups, then you'll need to boot off a USB drive (a live CD) and run (example)

```
 xfs_repair /dev/sdc1
```

on all your XFS partitions.

If one or more of your drives is failing then you will need to replace it.